# How to specify a range for the x axis in a matlab/octave plot?

Tags: octave

I have the following data set:

```
octave:4> data(1:10,:)
ans =

 Columns 1 through 10:

    198.000000000   2001.000000000      1.000000000     30.000000000      0.917600000      0.928000000      0.914700000      0.926900000      0.000133000      0.000108000
    199.000000000   2001.000000000      1.000000000     31.000000000      0.926800000      0.942600000      0.926600000      0.941300000      0.000160000      0.000133000
    200.000000000   2001.000000000      2.000000000      1.000000000      0.941400000      0.944700000      0.936400000      0.937300000      0.000083000      0.000160000
    201.000000000   2001.000000000      2.000000000      2.000000000      0.937400000      0.942100000      0.931800000      0.936400000      0.000103000      0.000083000
    202.000000000   2001.000000000      2.000000000      4.000000000      0.936600000      0.939700000      0.936600000      0.939400000      0.000033000      0.000103000
    203.000000000   2001.000000000      2.000000000      5.000000000      0.939300000      0.943900000      0.936500000      0.937100000      0.000074000      0.000033000
    204.000000000   2001.000000000      2.000000000      6.000000000      0.937200000      0.938900000      0.928200000      0.929600000      0.000107000      0.000074000
    205.000000000   2001.000000000      2.000000000      7.000000000      0.929500000      0.935200000      0.926100000      0.928800000      0.000091000      0.000107000
    206.000000000   2001.000000000      2.000000000      8.000000000      0.928900000      0.929200000      0.915300000      0.918700000      0.000139000      0.000091000
    207.000000000   2001.000000000      2.000000000      9.000000000      0.918800000      0.927800000      0.913500000      0.924000000      0.000143000      0.000139000

 Columns 11 through 14:

      0.013034000      0.010134000     -0.003166000      0.009034000
      0.015680000      0.015480000     -0.000520000      0.014180000
      0.008134000      0.003134000     -0.005166000     -0.004266000
      0.010094000      0.004494000     -0.005806000     -0.001206000
      0.003034000      0.003034000     -0.000066000      0.002734000
      0.007252000      0.004452000     -0.002948000     -0.002348000
      0.010486000      0.001486000     -0.009214000     -0.007814000
      0.008918000      0.005518000     -0.003582000     -0.000882000
      0.013622000      0.000022000     -0.013878000     -0.010478000
      0.014014000      0.008714000     -0.005586000      0.004914000
```

I define some variables to help identifying which specific columns I am using:

```
YEAR = 2;
MONTH = 3;
DAY = 4;
CLOSE = 8;
```

Then I want to plot the whole series so I do this:

```
figure(3)
xdates = datenum(data(:,YEAR),data(:,MONTH),data(:,DAY))
subplot(2,1,1); plot(xdates, data(:,CLOSE))
set(gca, "xtick", datenum (2000:2:2020,1,1));
set(gca,'xticklabel',{[]})
title("EURUSD 2000-2019");
subplot(2,1,2); plot(xdates, data(:,ATR))
set(gca, 'xtick', datenum (2000:2:2020,1,1));
datetick("x", 'yy/mm', "keepticks");
```

Then I get:

[image: subplot]

So far so good (the xlabels can not be read but that is ok, I can format with "YY" and they can be read). Now I want to display the graph between 2019,1,1 and 2020,1,1.
I have tried:

```
figure(3)
xdates = datenum(data(:,YEAR),data(:,MONTH),data(:,DAY))
subplot(2,1,1); plot(xdates, data(:,CLOSE))
set(gca, "xtick", datenum (2000:2:2020,1,1));
set(gca,'xticklabel',{[]})
xlim(datenum (2019:1:2020,1,1));
title("EURUSD 2000-2019");
subplot(2,1,2); plot(xdates, data(:,ATR))
set(gca, 'xtick', datenum (2000:2:2020,1,1));
xlim(datenum (2019:1:2020,1,1));
datetick("x", 'yy/mm', "keepticks");
```

But I get:

[image: xaxisrange2]

What shall be done to have the plot displaying values between 2019,1,1 and 2020,1,1?